# Buttons in seleium

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to automate this website where you can take quizzes. I tried to automate to press a button, but I can't.

```html
<div _ngcontent-tasso-universal-c22 class="tass-tart-quiz__button">
    <button class="tasso-button__green" _ngcontent-tasso-universal-c22>Go!</button>
</div>
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming language\Python\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("http://www.tassomai.com/")

login = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Sign in")
login.click()

e = browser.find_element_by_name("email")
e.send_keys("***********@mayfieldschool.net")

p = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
p.send_keys("*******")
p.submit()

button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("tasso-button__green")
button.click()
```

I tried this code in python, but it does not work: it sometimes logs me in, however, it doesn't let press the button.

How do I press this button with selenium?

Comment: There is no button with `tasso-button__green` class on the page. I believe that the green button should be visible after logging in. Try to wait until it becomes visible. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 1):

try using xpath to find the element change that button.click() to button.submit()
here is a simple code to login with selenium and geckodriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("write the site here")

username = "write your username here"
password = "write your pass here"

username_path = 'write xpath'
password_path = 'write xpath'
loginbutton_path = 'write xpath'

username_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(username_path)
pass_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_path)
button_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginbutton_path)

username_element.send_keys(username)
pass_element.send_keys(password)
button_element.submit()
```

for finding xpath right click on the thing you need and select inspect element then right click again on the highlighted codes and from copy select copy xpath then past it to code.

Answer (score 0):

You can first wait for the element to be clickable and then click on it.
You can do it like:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Go!']"))).click()
```

**Note: You have to add the following imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: it gives me this error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @shmifful Can you check if an iframe is present in the html structure?

Comment: and what is that?

Comment: Check the html structure and check if there is any `<iframe>` tag present in it